# WQL for enumerating all classes in a namespace

Tags: c#, wmi, enumeration, wmi-query, wql

I am able to use the following query successfully on WMI, but I am unable to make it more granular using the `__genus` property.

Works: `select * from meta_class where __class like "%win32%"`

Works: `select * from meta_class where __class like "%win32%" and __superclass like "%process%"`

Does not work: `select * from meta_class where __class like "%win32%" and __genus is 1`

Does not work: `select * from meta_class where __genus = 1`

I'm working on a C# project where I've scavenged all namespaces on a remote node, and I'm working on all classes within that namespace. I have a workaround utilizing `System.Management.ManagementClass`, but it is incredibly weird. Is there any way to query with the `__genus` property? I'm able to use other properties, but `__genus` seems like it doesn't work.

Thank you

Edit: Thanks megatron, totally skipped my mind to edit for code pieces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further research, the `__Genus` property should be available to query, however, due to the nature of a schema query, it seems to be purposefully excluded. Schema queries can only return class definitions, and not instances of a class. Class definitions always have `__Genus` set to 1, thereby eliminating the need to test the `__Genus` property of a class.